# Backbone.js nothing renders except when manually

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js

When loading up the page none of the JS seems to kick of, but when i manually do

```
var foo = new TrollMann;
foo.render();
```

things seem to work as it should. My first thoughts are that maybe some of the scripts are "missing" when some of the scripts first fire off, due to the fact that some of them are loaded via asp.net mvc RenderAction(). But im not sure.

Order.cshtml:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           window.ApplicationInfo = Backbone.Model.extend({
           });

           window.Trollmann = Backbone.View.extend({
               initialize: function () {
                   _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'wizardMethod');
               },

               render: function () {
                   this.wizardMethod();
                   return this;
               },

               wizardMethod: function () {
                   var myModel = new ApplicationInfo;
                   var steps = [
                    {
                    step_number: 1,
                    title: "Agfa Ris",
                    view: new AgfaRis({ model: myModel })
                },
                    {
                        step_number: 2,
                        title: "Merida",
                        view: new Merida({ model: myModel })
                    }
                ];

                    var view = new TilgangTrollmann({
                       model: myModel,
                       steps: steps
                   });
                   $("#current_step").html(view.render().el);
                   console.log("asd");
               }
           });

           window.TilgangTrollmann = Backbone.View.extend({
               id: 'trollmann',
               template: _.template($("#trollmann-template").html()),

               events: {
                   "click #next_step_btn": "nextStep",
                   "click #prev_step_btn": "prevStep"
               },

               initialize: function () {
                   _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                   this.currentStep = 0;
               },

               render: function () {
                   $(this.el).html(this.template);
                   this.progressIndicator = this.$("#progress_indicator");
                   this.title = this.$("h2#step_title");
                   this.currentStepcontainer = this.$(".current_step_container");
                   this.nextStepBtn = this.$("#next_step_btn");
                   this.prevStepBtn = this.$("#prev_step_btn");
                   this.renderCurrentStep();
                   return this;
               },

               renderCurrentStep: function () {
                   var currentStep = this.options.steps[this.currentStep];
                   if (!this.isFirstStep()) var prevStep = this.options.step[this.currentStep - 1];
                   var nextStep = this.options.steps[this.currentStep + 1];

                   this.title.html(currentStep.title);
                   this.currentView = currentStep.view;
                   console.log("asd");
                   this.currentStepcontainer.html(this.currentView.render());
                   console.log("asd2");

                   this.renderProgressIndicator();

                   if (prevStep) {
                       this.prevStepBtn.html("Forrige: " + prevStep.title).show();
                   } else {
                       this.prevStepBtn.hide();
                   };

                   if (nextStep) {
                       this.nextStepBtn.html("Neste: " + nextStep.title);
                   } else {
                       this.nextStepBtn.html("Fullfør");
                   };
               },

               renderProgressIndicator: function () {
                   this.progressIndicator.empty();
                   _.each(this.options.steps, _.bind(function (step) {
                       var text = "(" + step.step_number + ") " + step.title + ">>> ";
                       var el = this.make('span', {}, text);
                       if (step.step_number == this.currentStep + 1) $(el).addClass('active');
                       this.progressIndicator.append(el);
                   }, this));
               },

               nextStep: function () {
                   if (this.currentView.validate()) {
                       if (!this.isLastStep()) {
                           this.currentView.validate();
                           this.currentStep += 1;
                           this.renderCurrentStep()
                       } else {
                           this.save();
                       };
                   };
               },

               prevStep: function () {
                   if (!this.isfirstStep()) {
                       this.currentStep -= 1;
                       this.renderCurrentStep();
                   };
               },

               isFirstStep: function () {
                   return (this.currentStep == 0);
               },

               isLastStep: function () {
                   return (this.currentStep == this.options.steps.length - 1);
               }
           });

           var t = new Trollmann();
       });
    </script>
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="trollmann-template">
    <div id="progress_indicator"></div>
    <h2 id="step_title"></h2>
    <div class="current_step_container"></div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <a id="prev_step_btn" class="">Forrige:</a>
        <a id="next_step_button" class="">Neste:</a>
    </div>
</script>
<div id="current_step"></div>
```

These are called using RenderAction("Index", "Merida (or AgfaRis)", new { area = "_Systems" }); and these are the views.

AgfaRis(index.cshtml):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.AgfaRis = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: _.template($("#agfaris-template").html()),

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, "render");
                this.render();
            },

            render: function () {
                $(this.el).html(this.template);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="agfaris-template">
<p>AgfaRis</p>
</script>
```

Merida(index.cshtml):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.Merida = Backbone.View.extend({
            template: _.template($("#merida-template").html()),

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, "render");
                this.render();
            },

            render: function () {
                $(this.el).html(this.template);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="merida-template">
<p>Merida</p>
</script>
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: please provide a small introduction which explains what your problem is (which plugins/libraries you are using, what test you did etc.). With all this code I cannot answer (too much reverse engineering!)

Comment: Have you tried adding 'this.render()' to your Trollmann view 'initialize' function?  I don't see you calling render for that view anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... It seems it's not rendering because you never actually call `t.render()`.  In most Backbone examples, `render()` is implicitly called because a model is set on a view, and that model is tied to the view's `render()` function.

More specifically, when initializing a view you'd normally have a call where you bind your view's `render()` function to a model being set/changed, like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    // ... your init stuff here ...
}
```

Whenever the model is changed, a `change` event is fired which triggers your view and calls `render()`.

However, in your case you only seem to be using the View functionality of Backbone, no Model stuff... So the easiest way to make your stuff render would be to add a explicit call to render in Order.cshtml after you create your `Trollmann`, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       window.ApplicationInfo = Backbone.Model.extend({
       });

       window.Trollmann = Backbone.View.extend({
           ...
       });

       window.TilgangTrollmann = Backbone.View.extend({
           ...
       });

       var t = new Trollmann();
       // Add the following line
       t.render();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was related to this. I solved it by adding a script tag at the bottom of the page with var t = .... and t.render().